# Using mysql to update a row in a relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables

users

```
- user_id
- username
- password
- api_key
```

orders

```
- order_id
- user_id
- product
```

how I can update the product selecting the user based on the api key?

i mean:

```
UPDATE orders SET product = "" 
WHERE order.user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE api_key = "xxxx");
```

The SQL statement is just the expected behaviour..

Comment: this query works like you want to, so what is your problem

Comment: I don't get it.Are you looking for a "Yes" "No" answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE api_key = 'xxxx'
```

may return more than 1 rows, in which case you should use the operator `IN`:

```
UPDATE orders 
SET product = '' 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE api_key = 'xxxx');
```

Or you can do it with a join:

```
UPDATE orders o
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = o.user_id 
SET o.product = '' 
WHERE u.api_key = 'xxxx';
```

Note that setting a column's value to an empty string is generally not a good idea.
It would be better to set it to `null`.

Comment: I tried both answers but in SQL I see always  0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0021 seconds.)

Comment: @reptc3 This means that there are no rows in orders under these conditions. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: now worked... I was trying to update an equal value.